# javascript works in IE8, sometimes in IE7

Tags: internet-explorer, extjs

I have a javascript component that worked in our previous release.  However, we made a bunch of changes in this last release.  Mostly small feature adds.  One (or more) of them is causing a small number of our user base to not work.  Information from our help desk paints a confusing picture.

The component is used in three places.  For all users in IE8+ not running in compatability mode, all three work fine.  Some users were in compatability mode, and saw all three not work.  One user in compatability mode saw ONE of the three not work...which is really comfusing.  All users in compatability mode were fixed when they switched out.  A final subset o users is in IE7, and we're seeing that ONE of the three is not working.

The kicker is that we can't replicate the failure in house in compatability mode.  Sarcastic "Yay!".

So we're staring at code and looking for stuff that won't work in IE7 but will in IE8.  Can someone tell me if, from the following couple functions anything jumps out at you?  These are a couple of the new features that we've deemed most likely to be suspects.

Probably worth mentioning that ExtJS 4.2.1's grid is part of the component.

```
function setDisplayOfPagingMessage(displayProperty, text1, text2) {
var elements = Ext.select(".x-toolbar-text").elements;
for(var i=0;i<elements.length;i++) {
    if(elements[i].innerHTML.indexOf(text1) > -1 || elements[i].innerHTML.indexOf(text2) > -1) {
        elements[i].style.display = displayProperty;
    }
}
}
```

and

```
function setHeaderCheckboxAltText(altText) {
var els = Ext.select('.x-column-header-checkbox');
if(els.elements.length>0) {
    var element = els.elements[0];
    var txt = element.innerHTML;
    var index = txt.indexOf('x-column-header-text');
    index = txt.indexOf('>', index);
    if(index==-1)
        return;
    element.innerHTML = txt.substring(0, index) + " title='" + altText + "' " + txt.substring(index, txt.length);
}
}
```

Comment: There were probably errors on the console. If so, what were they?

Comment: And you cannot use console.log in IE8 or lower.

Comment: I should mention that displayProperty in the first block with be either 'none' or 'inline' depending.

Comment: @user2864740 - You'd think.  But according to our help desk guys, they say users are saying there is no little yellow triangle warning button that we asked them to look for.  We kind of think that they aren't understanding what we're asking them to look for and are requesting more info from some users.  But that's what they say at the moment.

Comment: I think this is too vague for anyone to be able to help appropriately. Also, don't use compat mode, download the virtual machines to test, compat mode doesn't behave exactly like the installed version.

Comment: @EvanTrimboli - Unfortunately, I agree that it is vague.  Which is why I can't fix it.  I was hoping something would jump out at someone who deals with browser compatability stuff more often than I and they might say "Oh, don't do X, it's not supported by IE7."